# Google Maps marker drop on building not street

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently making a custom map using the Google Maps API. So far I have inserted a kml layer using geoXml3, and have written the code to determine if the location of the marker (dropped by an autocomplete address search) is contained within the kml boundary.

Unfortunately I seemed to forget that the marker drops on the street outside the building, not the building itself. This is important as the kml layer is over buildings, and doesn't bleed on to the street.

Is there a way to get the marker to drop on the building instead of the street? If not, are there any alternative ways I could complete what I'm trying to achieve?

Cheers.

Comment: What does your code look like?  If the geocode data in the area you are interested in doesn't have "ROOFTOP" accuracy, the markers will end up on the street.  You could investigate the Places API, it _might_ have different/better data, but I wouldn't expect it to.

Comment: Yes, geocoder will (almost always) want to return an address, it will tell you where to drive to, rather than tell you where the building is.  One idea: you could make the marker draggable, ask the client to drag to the exact location, then push a button, then you check the klm